# Stop vbscript deactivating current window when running?

Tags: windows-8, vbscript

I'm trying to write a simple script to fill in login details on a program that requires signing in using a keyboard shortcut.

```
set wshshell = wscript.CreateObject("wscript.shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "username{tab}passowrd{enter}"
```

This works as desired on my work computer (xp) but on my home computer (windows 8) the keyboard shortcut deactivates the current window so that the details are not entered.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look into the shell's AppActivate method. You could write something like this:

```
boolSuccess = False
do until boolSuccess = True
    boolSuccess = WshShell.AppActivate("AppName")
    WshShell.sleep 500
loop    
WshShell.SendKeys "username{tab}password{enter}"
```

This will move the focus to your target app, and then send the keys. The tragically kludgey part is that you may need that 'sleep' between the AppActivate and the SendKeys to be sure that your target app has time to receive the focus.